# Why is git submodules saying there isn't a url when there is one even when I try different versions of it?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to pull a git submodule but it complains that the url is not found. Why is that? Everything seems in order:

- the folder with code in the submodule seems to be there
- the .modules file seems right
- the url doesn't seem wrong compared to other ones. I tried https but didn't help.

So what's the issue?

See the modules file is correct:

```
$ git submodule update && git submodule init
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg' in .gitmodules
$ rm -rf coq-projects/lin-alg
$ cat .gitmodules | grep lin-alg
[submodule "coq-projects/lin-alg"]
    path = coq-projects/lin-alg
    url = git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git
$ git submodule update && git submodule init

Submodule path 'coq-projects/lin-alg': checked out 'aa5a7cc4105fd20debf4c13a7d40392e34631610'
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg' in .gitmodules
$
$ ls coq-projects/lin-alg/
_CoqProject  description  examples  extras  filesInOrder  first_page.v  LICENSE  LinAlg  Makefile  README.md  support
$ cat .gitmodules | grep lin-alg
[submodule "coq-projects/lin-alg"]
    path = coq-projects/lin-alg
    url = git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git
```

look the https is not needed the other repos look fine:

```
[submodule "coq-projects/fermat4"]
    path = coq-projects/fermat4
    url = git@github.com:coq-contribs/fermat4.git
```

this also failed:

```
$ rm -rf coq-projects/lin-alg
$ git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg https://github.com/coq-contribs/lin-alg.git coq-projects/lin-alg
Reactivating local git directory for submodule 'coq-projects/lin-alg'.

$
$ cat .gitmodules | grep lin-alg
[submodule "coq-projects/lin-alg"]
    path = coq-projects/lin-alg
    url = https://github.com/coq-contribs/lin-alg.git
$ git submodule update && git submodule init
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg' in .gitmodules
```

this still failed:

```
$ rm -rf coq-projects/lin-alg
$
$ git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
Reactivating local git directory for submodule 'coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10'.
$ cat .gitmodules | grep lin-alg
[submodule "coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10"]
    path = coq-projects/lin-alg
    url = git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git
$ git submodule update && git submodule init
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg' in .gitmodules
```

I thought that once the submodule name had the 8.10 it would work -- which matches his .gitmodules file https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/blob/e89e89cf3b3ee24d04b2dc5e965e787f714340f0/.gitmodules#L134

I don't understand why there are two coq-projects/coq-projects

```
$ cat .submodules | grep coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg
cat: .submodules: No such file or directory
$ ls coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg
ls: cannot access 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg': No such file or directory
```

it's not there:

```
$ opam list | grep lin-alg
$
```

---

## New attempt

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
Adding existing repo at 'coq-projects/lin-alg' to the index
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule update --init coq-projects/lin-alg
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ (cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)
]make -f Makefile.coq Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make -f Makefile.coq all
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
W: This Makefile was generated by Coq 8.15.2
W: while the current Coq version is 8.10.2
COQC support/equal_syntax.v
COQC support/more_syntax.v
File "./support/more_syntax.v", line 18, characters 0-39:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
...
roup_sgroup] : ring_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [ring_monoid; Build_monoid] : ring_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group; group_monoid] : ring_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_group_group; group_monoid; monoid_on_def;
                   Build_monoid] : abelian_group >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_group; group_monoid] : abelian_group >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_group_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_group_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_monoid >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_monoid >-> monoid.
New coercion path [Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid;
                   monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_monoid_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_monoid_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [Build_group; group_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : group_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_group; group_monoid] : group_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [group_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : group >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[group_monoid] : group >-> monoid. [ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
COQC LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 19, characters 0-31:
Warning: There is no option Automatic Coercions Import.
[unknown-option,option]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning: Use of “Require” inside a section is deprecated.
[require-in-section,deprecated]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_on_def; Build_ring] : field_on >-> ring is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring] : field_on >-> ring.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_on_def; Build_ring] : field >-> ring is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring] : field >-> ring. [ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   Build_abelian_group] : cring_on >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group] : cring_on >-> abelian_group.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   Build_abelian_group] : cring >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group] : cring >-> abelian_group.
New coercion path [Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   Build_abelian_group] : ring_on >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group] : ring_on >-> abelian_group.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   Build_abelian_group] : field_on >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group] : field_on >-> abelian_group.
New coercion path [ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; Build_abelian_group] : ring >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group] : ring >-> abelian_group.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   Build_abelian_group] : field >-> abelian_group is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group] : field >-> abelian_group.
[ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_abelian_group; abelian_group_group; group_on_def;
                   Build_group] : abelian_group_on >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_abelian_group; abelian_group_group] : abelian_group_on >-> group.
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group;
                   group_on_def; Build_group] : cring_on >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group] : cring_on >-> group.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group; group_on_def;
                   Build_group] : cring >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group] : cring >-> group.
New coercion path [abelian_group_group; group_on_def; Build_group] : abelian_group >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_group] : abelian_group >-> group.
New coercion path [Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group; group_on_def;
                   Build_group] : ring_on >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group] : ring_on >-> group.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group;
                   group_on_def; Build_group] : field_on >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group] : field_on >-> group.
New coercion path [ring_group; abelian_group_group; group_on_def; Build_group] : ring >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group; abelian_group_group] : ring >-> group.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group; group_on_def;
                   Build_group] : field >-> group is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_group] : field >-> group.
[ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_group_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_group_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [abelian_monoid_on_def; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
                   Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
                   sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_monoid >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_monoid_on_def; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
 abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_monoid >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_monoid_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_monoid_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
                   sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_sgroup_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_sgroup_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_sgroup >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_sgroup >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : cring_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : cring_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : cring >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : cring >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : abelian_group >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : abelian_group >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : ring_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : ring_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : field_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : field_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : ring >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : ring >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup;
                   abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def; Build_sgroup] : field >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : field >-> sgroup.
[ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : cring_on >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid] : cring_on >-> monoid_on.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : cring >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid] : cring >-> monoid_on.
New coercion path [Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : ring_on >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[ring_monoid] : ring_on >-> monoid_on.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : field_on >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid] : field_on >-> monoid_on.
New coercion path [ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : ring >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[ring_on_def; ring_monoid] : ring >-> monoid_on.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
                   abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def] : field >-> monoid_on is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid] : field >-> monoid_on.
[ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 22, characters 0-40:
Warning:
New coercion path [Build_group; group_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : group_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_group; group_monoid] : group_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [group_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : group >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[group_monoid] : group >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
                   abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_group_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_group_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_monoid_monoid; monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_monoid >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_monoid >-> monoid.
New coercion path [Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid;
                   monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_monoid_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_monoid_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : cring_on >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : cring_on >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup] : cring_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : cring_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid] : cring_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_cring; cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : cring_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid;
                   monoid_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : cring >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
 sgroup_on_def] : cring >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid;
                   monoid_sgroup] : cring >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : cring >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [cring_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid] : cring >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[cring_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : cring >-> monoid.
New coercion path [abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
                   Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid;
                   monoid_on_def; Build_monoid] : abelian_group >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_monoid] : abelian_group >-> monoid.
New coercion path [ring_monoid; Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : ring_on >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
 sgroup_on_def] : ring_on >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [ring_monoid; Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup] : ring_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : ring_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [ring_monoid; Build_monoid] : ring_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : ring_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : field_on >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : field_on >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup] : field_on >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup;
 Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : field_on >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [Build_field; field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid;
                   Build_monoid] : field_on >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[Build_field; field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def;
 abelian_group_abelian_monoid; Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : field_on >-> monoid.
New coercion path [ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup;
                   sgroup_on_def] : ring >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
 sgroup_on_def] : ring >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid; monoid_sgroup] : ring >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : ring >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid] : ring >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : ring >-> monoid.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid;
                   monoid_sgroup; sgroup_on_def] : field >-> sgroup_on is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup;
 sgroup_on_def] : field >-> sgroup_on.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid;
                   monoid_sgroup] : field >-> sgroup is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 abelian_monoid_abelian_sgroup; Build_abelian_sgroup; abelian_sgroup_sgroup] : field >-> sgroup.
New coercion path [field_ring; ring_on_def; ring_monoid; Build_monoid] : field >-> monoid is ambiguous with existing
[field_ring; ring_group; abelian_group_on_def; abelian_group_abelian_monoid;
 Build_abelian_monoid; abelian_monoid_monoid] : field >-> monoid.
[ambiguous-paths,typechecker]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 23, characters 0-28:
Warning: Use of “Require” inside a section is deprecated.
[require-in-section,deprecated]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 24, characters 0-27:
Warning: Use of “Require” inside a section is deprecated.
[require-in-section,deprecated]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 25, characters 0-41:
Warning: Use of “Require” inside a section is deprecated.
[require-in-section,deprecated]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 70, characters 0-35:
Warning: Adding and removing hints in the core database implicitly is
deprecated. Please specify a hint database.
[implicit-core-hint-db,deprecated]
File "./LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v", line 88, characters 0-4:
Error:
 (in proof Zero_times_a_vector_gives_zero): Attempt to save an incomplete proof

make[2]: *** [Makefile.coq:764: LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.vo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile.coq:387: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

still fails.

Comment: `.submodules` isn't a thing; what did you expect it to be? `.gitmodules` contains information needed to run `git clone` on submodules that aren't yet cloned. This information gets copied *from* `.gitmodules` to other places, after which the information *in* the `.gitmodules` isn't consulted any more, so it's a good idea for testing purposes to re-clone to a test location (test VM, test machine, whatever).

Comment: Meanwhile, as for `No url found for submodule path 'coq-projects/coq-projects/lin-alg'`: each commit that contains one or more *gitlinks* (entries that go into Git's index with `mode 160000`) results in these gitlinks. Those entries have a path name, just like any index / staging-area entry (use `git ls-files --stage` to see them all, and note that there tend to be a lot so you might want to redirect the output). It's those paths that, if they don't yet exist on disk somewhere, require consulting `.gitmodules` to `git clone` the right source repository.

Comment: So, you apparently have a bad gitlink in a commit, at this point, if that's not the path you wanted. You can't fix a bad commit; you'll have to eject it (stop using it) and make a new-and-improved replacement in the usual ways (see `git rebase` and `git commit --amend` for instance).

Comment: It's probably unrelated to your problem, but you perform `git submodule update && git submodule init` above after cloning your repository. You should swap the order of the two commands, since `git submodule update` will do nothing _before_ `git submodule init` has occurred. You can also force initialization as part of the update with a single command: `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75441920/how-does-one-make-sure-that-coq-project-installed-correctly-when-it-doesnt-seem

Answer (score 0):

No idea what changed but this is the command I am running right now:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
Adding existing repo at 'coq-projects/lin-alg' to the index
```

seems to work.