# How does one make sure that coq project installed correctly when it doesn't seem to appear on opam list?

Tags: coq, opam

I tried installing `lin-alg-8.10` using the instructions I was told from [proverbot's repo](https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001) using coq 8.10:

```
# - Create the 8.10 switch
opam switch
opam switch create coq-8.10 4.07.1
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)
opam pin add -y coq 8.10.2
git submodule add -f --name coq-projects/lin-alg-8.10 git@github.com:HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10.git coq-projects/lin-alg
git submodule update --init coq-projects/lin-alg
#
(cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)
```

after a long set of output of the commands it seems it installed -- due to the lack of errors -- but grepping `opam list` gives literally no output.

How do I confirm I did install lin-alg-8.10 correctly under the stuggested coq version (I assume 8.9)?

---

## Full output of commands:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ (cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile.coq
make -f Makefile.coq Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make -f Makefile.coq all
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'real-all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
coq_makefile -f _CoqProject -o Makefile.coq
make -f Makefile.coq Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'Makefile'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make -f Makefile.coq install
make[1]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
INSTALL first_page.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg/
INSTALL support/equal_syntax.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/more_syntax.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/finite.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Fn.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/Map2.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_functionspace.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrices.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Mmn.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL LinAlg/alt_build_vecsp.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/infinite_sequences.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/algebra_omissions.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/arb_intersections.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/subspaces.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/antisymmetric_matrices.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/symmetric_matrices.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/up_lo_triang_mat.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/seq_set.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_seq.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/empty.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/conshdtl.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/const.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/pointwise.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/modify_seq.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/mult_by_scalars.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/Map_embed.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/subseqs.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums2.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_seq_lengths.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distribution_lemmas.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_between_subsets.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_combinations.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/spans.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/algebraic_span_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_comb_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/direct_sum.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dependence.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dep_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/random_facts.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/finite_subsets.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/has_n_elements.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/counting_elements.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/bases.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_from_generating_sets.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_theorem.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_corollaries.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_finite_dim.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/maxlinindepsubsets.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_dim.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_bases.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Linear_Algebra_by_Friedberg_Insel_Spence.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Lin_trafos.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/trivial_spaces.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrix_multiplication.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL extras/ring_module.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Inter_intersection.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/finite_misc.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/restrict.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Matrix_related_defs.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/before_after.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/matrix_algebra.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Equality_structures.vo /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL first_page.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg/
INSTALL support/equal_syntax.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/more_syntax.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/finite.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Fn.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/Map2.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_functionspace.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrices.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Mmn.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL LinAlg/alt_build_vecsp.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/infinite_sequences.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/algebra_omissions.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/arb_intersections.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/subspaces.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/antisymmetric_matrices.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/symmetric_matrices.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/up_lo_triang_mat.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/seq_set.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_seq.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/empty.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/conshdtl.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/const.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/pointwise.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/modify_seq.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/mult_by_scalars.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/Map_embed.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/subseqs.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums2.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_seq_lengths.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distribution_lemmas.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_between_subsets.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_combinations.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/spans.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/algebraic_span_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_comb_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/direct_sum.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dependence.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dep_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/random_facts.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/finite_subsets.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/has_n_elements.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/counting_elements.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/bases.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_from_generating_sets.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_theorem.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_corollaries.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_finite_dim.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/maxlinindepsubsets.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_dim.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_bases.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Linear_Algebra_by_Friedberg_Insel_Spence.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Lin_trafos.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/trivial_spaces.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrix_multiplication.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL extras/ring_module.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Inter_intersection.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/finite_misc.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/restrict.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Matrix_related_defs.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/before_after.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/matrix_algebra.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Equality_structures.v /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL first_page.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg/
INSTALL support/equal_syntax.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/more_syntax.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/vecspaces_verybasic.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/finite.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Fn.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/Map2.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL examples/vecspace_functionspace.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrices.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/vecspace_Mmn.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL LinAlg/alt_build_vecsp.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/infinite_sequences.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/algebra_omissions.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/arb_intersections.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/subspaces.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/antisymmetric_matrices.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/symmetric_matrices.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/up_lo_triang_mat.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL support/seq_set.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_seq.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/empty.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/conshdtl.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/const.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/pointwise.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/modify_seq.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/mult_by_scalars.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/Map_embed.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/subseqs.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/sums2.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_seq_lengths.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/concat_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_equality_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distribution_lemmas.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/seq_set_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/omit_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/distinct_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/cast_between_subsets.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_combinations.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/spans.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/algebraic_span_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_comb_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/direct_sum.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dependence.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/lin_dep_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL support/random_facts.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/finite_subsets.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/has_n_elements.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL support/counting_elements.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//support
INSTALL LinAlg/bases.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_from_generating_sets.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_theorem.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/replacement_corollaries.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/bases_finite_dim.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/maxlinindepsubsets.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_dim.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/subspace_bases.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Linear_Algebra_by_Friedberg_Insel_Spence.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL LinAlg/Lin_trafos.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//LinAlg
INSTALL examples/trivial_spaces.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL examples/Matrix_multiplication.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//examples
INSTALL extras/ring_module.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Inter_intersection.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/finite_misc.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/restrict.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Matrix_related_defs.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/before_after.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/matrix_algebra.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
INSTALL extras/Equality_structures.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
make[2]: Entering directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/afs/cs.stanford.edu/u/brando9/proverbot9001/coq-projects/lin-alg'
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam list | grep lin-alg
```

---

## Was it installed with coq 8.9 or 8.10?

it is also very confusing which coq version is using given the final output of the `opam switch` command:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~/proverbot9001 $ opam switch
#  switch    compiler                    description
→  coq-8.10  ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1  coq-8.10
   coq-8.15  ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1  coq-8.15
   coq-8.9   ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1  coq-8.9
   default   ocaml.5.0.0                 default

[NOTE] Current switch is set locally through the OPAMSWITCH variable.
       The current global system switch is coq-8.9.
```

---

related links:

- similar issue from git repo: https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/81
- old failed installation using `(cd coq-projects/lin-alg && make "$@" && make install)` https://github.com/UCSD-PL/proverbot9001/issues/61
- lin-alg-8.10 doesn't seem to be the official lin-alg repo so here is the link to the repo I am using: https://github.com/HazardousPeach/lin-alg-8.10
- discussion that coq 8.9 might be the right coq version: https://github.com/coq-contribs/lin-alg/issues/5

Answer (score 1):

> but grepping `opam list` gives literally no output.

This is normal. `make install` just copies files around but does not update `opam`'s own package registry (because `make install` is agnostic to `opam`). Hence packages installed that way won't appear in `opam list`.

You can install local versions of packages using something like `opam pin add coq-lin-alg /path/to/lin-alg-8.10` (but this can be brittle if a released package has changed its build script in the meantime).

> How do I confirm I did install lin-alg-8.10 correctly under the stuggested coq version (I assume 8.9)?

Look at the paths in the install output:

```
INSTALL extras/Equality_structures.glob /lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/.opam/coq-8.10/lib/coq//user-contrib/LinAlg//extras
```

The name of the switch can be seen as a directory: `.../.opam/coq-8.10/...`.

The next step is to open a new Coq file and try to `Require Import` a module from the newly installed library.

> it is also very confusing which coq version is using given the final output of the `opam switch` command

The answer to "What coq version is CURRENTLY being used" is in the first part of the output (where the arrow points to), ignoring the warning. The warning tells you that it will no longer be the case once the environment variable `OPAMSWITCH` is unset, which will probably be when you open a new terminal (unless a start-up script sets it again, but you probably shouldn't use `--set-switch` to begin with, see below).

You would have a less confusing output if you switched like this:

```
# Global switch (persists across shell sessions)
opam switch coq-8.10
eval $(opam env)

# Check: no warnings
opam switch
```

instead of

```
# Local switch (via environment variables; only for the current session)
eval $(opam env --switch=coq-8.10 --set-switch)

# Check: warning (if the global switch isn't 8.10 already)
opam switch
# ...

[NOTE] Current switch is set locally through the OPAMSWITCH variable.
       The current global system switch is coq-8.9.
```